# continue running a keypress function after another keypress tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have a game where a square can move around and jump, but whenever it jumps, it stops all horizontal movement until you press the left or right keys again, I was wondering if there was a way to continue horizontal movement after hitting the up key to jump? my code is

```
import Tkinter as tkinter
def is_even(n):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        retVal = True
    else:
        retVal = False
    return retVal
class gameScreen:
    def move(self, event):
        d = self.getdir(event.keysym)
        self.canvas.move(self.char, d[0], d[1])

        if self.collision():
            self.canvas.move(self.char, -d[0], -d[1])
    def jump(self):
        j = 0
        from time import sleep
        jump = [4, 4, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -4, -4]
        for i in range(0, (len(jump)*2)):
            x = jump[j]
            print x
            self.canvas.move(self.char, 0, -x)
            if not  is_even(i):
                j +=1
            self.canvas.update()
            sleep(.05)

    def touchingGround(self, event):
        self.canvas.move(self.char, 0, 5)

        if self.collision():
            retVal = True
        else:
            retVal = False
        self.canvas.move(self.char, 0, -5)
        return retVal

    def onKey(self, event):
        keys = ["Left", "Right"]
        if event.keysym == "Up":
            if self.touchingGround(event):
                self.jump()
        else:
            if event.keysym in keys:
                self.move(event)

    def collision(self):
        coords = self.canvas.coords(self.char)
        collision =  len(self.canvas.find_overlapping(coords[0]-1,
                         coords[1]-1, coords[2]-1, coords[3]-1)) >=2
        return collision
    def getdir(self, s):

        direction = {"Left":[-5, 0], "Right":[5, 0]}

        try:
            retVal = direction[s]
        except KeyError:
            retVal =False
        return retVal




    def __init__(self, master):
        self.objects = []
        self.master = master
        master.title("Game")
        self.img = tkinter.PhotoImage(file = "platformer.gif")
        self.canvas = tkinter.Canvas(master, width=500, height=500)

        self.canvas.pack(expand="YES",fill="both")

        self.objects.append(self.canvas.create_rectangle(2, 500, 500, 400,
                            fill="grey"))
        self.char = self.canvas.create_rectangle(2, 400, 52, 350, 
                                                 fill="red")
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
        master.bind("<Key>", self.onKey)        

root = tkinter.Tk()
my_gui = gameScreen(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: you need to add acceleration to your code rather than just direct moment commands.

Comment: im kinda new to tkinter, can you explain what that means?

Comment: right now you have "when I push a button I move `x` amount, when I stop pushing the button it stops moving", But if you think about it in general games, when you push the button, the object starts moving, and when you stop pushing the button, the object still moves but slows down. IE the button is accelerating the object, not directly moving. This allows an object to jump, but still continue movement, forward (slowing down) but still movement

Comment: okay, that makes more sense, thanks.